# Peticiones a Swagger

Tags: jquery, swagger

Buenos días, estoy haciendo una web que realice conexiones a una base de datos Velneo, haciendo uso de Swagger.
He conseguido realizar consultar a la base de datos del siguiente modo:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", $urlEnvio, false);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept" ,"application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type" ,"application/json");

xmlhttp.send( JSON.stringify($datos) );

alert(xmlhttp.response);
```

donde $urlEnvio es la url que conecta con Swagger, y la variable datos contiene los datos provenientes de un formulario.
El problema es que no se como aplicarle filtros a la búsqueda, por ejemplo que me saque los usuarios cuyo nombre sea uno.
Alguien me puede orientar? Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: No he usado nunca swagger, pero te diría que ahora mismo estás compartiendo sólo el código de la petición de datos en el lado del cliente, y la consulta se hace en la parte del servidor, por lo que creo que faltaría compartir el código de la página que se solicita (`$urlEnvio`) para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: viste este video? creo que lo explican bastante bien https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_-JrOyuXmU&list=PL-bVpgNOlmip5RiPJgYdLj1nJJx7HFDoW&index=11 asi el $urlEnvio lo fabricas según los parámetros que te da swagger Saludos